# How to Change Font Color Excel after generate from VB 6

Tags: excel, vba

.Worksheets("PERSONAL TARGET").CELLS(iRow, 1).Value = "Sales" & "(" & sMyDate & ")"

Upstair is my return value

-the code is vb 6 code

How to change the font color to red

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
.Worksheets("PERSONAL TARGET").CELLS(iRow, 1).Font.Color = vbRed
```

Comment: i wan return .Worksheets("PERSONAL TARGET").CELLS(iRow, 1).Value = "Sales" & "(" & sMyDate & ")" and add font.color ..... value need maintain

Comment: @JHOng It works fine for me.  Here is a sample excel file. https://1drv.ms/u/s!Al2YxxyQYr5K9kzU23OxXT9PAHyS?e=3E2e9i